# Can't Enter Break mode at this time, while adding code to sheet programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on VBA Tool,
i am trying to add code to the sheet programmatically
here is my code,

```
Public Function Add_NodePairingCode(ByRef wb As Workbook)
    Dim xPro1 As VBProject
    Dim xCom1 As VBComponent
    Dim xMod1 As CodeModule
    Dim xLine As Long
    Sheets("Node Pairing").Activate
    Sheets("Node Pairing").Unprotect
    With wb
        Set xPro1 = wb.VBProject
        Set xCom1 = xPro1.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName)
        Set xMod1 = xCom1.CodeModule
        With xMod1
            xLine = .CreateEventProc("SelectionChange", "WorkSheet") 'Getting error at this line
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   Application.DisplayAlerts = False "
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   Dim KeyCells As Range "
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   Dim WS_Count As Integer"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   Dim I As Integer"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   Dim lnRow As Long, lnCol As Long"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   lnRow = 2 "
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count"
             xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   lnCol = Sheets(""Node Pairing"").Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=""Use For Mac"", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   Set KeyCells = Range(Cells(2, lnCol), Cells(2, lnCol).End(xlDown))"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _"
             xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "       Is Nothing Then"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "       For I = 1 To WS_Count"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "           If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name = ""Mac Table"" Then"
            xLine = xLine + 1

            .InsertLines xLine, "               If MsgBox(""Changing Use For Mac flag, will delete Mac Tables, Do You Want to Continue?"", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then "
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "                   Sheets(""Mac Table"").Delete"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "                   Exit Sub"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "               Else"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "                   Exit Sub"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "               End If"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "           End If"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "       Next I"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   End If"
            xLine = xLine + 1
            .InsertLines xLine, "   Application.DisplayAlerts = True "
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

i am not getting what did i do wrong, i tried all the ways, such as making function public and executing it, i looked into stackoverflow for solution, i could able to find related quesions but, couldn't find solution.
anyone can help me with this

Comment: `With wb ... End With` is useless in your code. Try adding a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3".

Comment: @FaneDuru i have commented unwanted with block, the reference for  "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" ia already added, still i am getting same error, any other solutions?

Comment: can anyone provide solution?

Comment: What error do you receive at that specified line?

Comment: @FaneDuru i recieve this error message: Can't Enter Break mode at this time (Query Title)

Comment: @FaneDuru i got the solution, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had gone through all the possibilities,
i found why the error was happening and the reason was,

when i called this particular function, my excel sheet was calculating some values (excel formulas) in the cells in background, meanwhile this function was trying to customize sheet code in compile mode, because of this reason my tool was giving `VBA` Error `Can't Enter Break mode at this time`

what i found the solution is: i have added saperate button on the master sheet and added same code (Functionality) to that button.
now i can able to run my tool parfectly without any error,

hope this would help someone :)